# Object.keys(this) from prototype method

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have following simple code:

```js
function DataSet() {
  this.foo = 'foo';
  this.bar = 'bar';
}

DataSet.prototype.getDataSetProps = function() {
  return Object.keys(this);
};
```

My IDE underlines `this` parameter with a wrong type warning message:

> Argument type DataSet is not assignable to parameter type {}

I already checked the type of `this` - and it's `Object`. Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: Which IDE is it? Your code seems to work, so it is definitely the IDE that tells you something wrong!

Comment: I guess your IDE doesn't deal well with js

Comment: How are you invoking the `getDataSetProps()`?

Comment: this doesn't look like a warning JS usually throws. Are you coding this in c# editor?

Comment: My IDE is PHPstorm and getDataSetProps() is called with:
const dataSet = new DataSet();
dataSet. getDataSetProps();

And yes, all works like expected, but i wonder where this message come from